# Why do I accidentally create files called ":wq"?

Tags: bash, vim

Sometimes when I am using `vim`, I find that I have accidentally created files called `:wq` or other commands I use internally from `vim`. In this case, it was a file which I was working on and I believe I saved this file as `:wq` somehow.

Has anyone ever experienced this and what accidental keystrokes am I making which does this?

I tend to use `bash`, but this happens regardless of the OS I am using.

Comment: `bash` is not an `os`.

Comment: thanks - I am aware of that. Bash is a shell, RHEL, Ubuntu, Fedora, etc. are OSs. I am stating that it happens in Bash, so this may be dependent upon my use of Bash, however, it seems to happen regardless of my OS, so it it not an OS problem.

Comment: Your sentence can be read that way but naively reads the way I read it. And yes, neither of those things is at all related to the problem.

Comment: apparently this be being closed as not being about programming. I guess this isn't actually a programming question, so that makes sense - but which stackexchange should this go to?

Comment: The votes are for superuser.

Comment: Thanks - SO and SU tend to overlap in my mind - I need to get better about consciously deciding before I post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you write it twice, because the `:w` accepts a parameter as file name to save the buffer, like:

```
:wq :wq
```

Answer (score 3):

If you type `:w :wq` by accident or `:w q` you will create `:wq` and `q` files.

I often create a `2` file in a similar fashion